# Подскажите, как убрать ошибку The table '/tmp/mysql/#sql_xxxxx' is full

Tags: mysql, opencart

Подскажите, как убрать ошибку `The table '/tmp/mysql/#sql_xxxxx' is full`

Ubuntu server 15.10, php5.6, nginx 1.9.3, mysql 5.7 в виртуальной машине под Hyper-V в Windows 10

Настраиваю seo-url в opencart 2, который стоит в подкаталоге сайта на joomla 3.5
После включения seo в настройках opencart

В логе mysql появляются ошибки

> [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace innodb_temporary ran out of space. Please
>   add another file or use  'autoextend' for the last file in setting
>   innodb_temp_data_file_path
>
> [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: The table '/tmp/mysql/#sql_c76e_2' is full
>   [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: The table '/tmp/mysql/#sql_c76e_3' is full

Сделал так

```
mkdir /tmp/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /tmp/mysql
service mysql restart
```

Права есть, но в /tmp/mysql/ ни одного файла нет.

В mysqld.cnf

Секция InnoDB

```
innodb_flush_method            = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 5M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1 
innodb_file_per_table          = 1 
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 8M
innodb_max_undo_log_size       = 50M
innodb_temp_data_file_path     = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:512M
```

Если убрать ограничение до 512 М, то этот файл заполняет все свободное место за несколько минут.

```
innodb_data_file_path          = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 8 
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 8 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct    = 75
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 
sync_binlog                    = 0 
innodb_io_capacity             = 600
innodb_io_capacity_max         = 1000
innodb_read_io_threads         = 32
innodb_write_io_threads        = 16
innodb_fast_shutdown           = 0 
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct     = 0
```

Сосотояние файловой системы

```
# df -h                                   
Файл.система   Размер Использовано  Дост Использовано% Cмонтировано в
udev             5,0G            0  5,0G            0% /dev
tmpfs            1,0G         110M  915M           11% /run
/dev/sda2         35G          22G   12G           65% /
tmpfs            5,0G            0  5,0G            0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            5,0M            0  5,0M            0% /run/lock
tmpfs            5,0G            0  5,0G            0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        511M         3,4M  508M            1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1,0G            0  1,0G            0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка сообщает о том, что у вас заканчивается место в табличном пространстве InnoDB, которое вы ограничили 512Мб

```
innodb_temp_data_file_path     = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:512M
```

Когда вы снимаете ограничение, табличное пространство начинает расти и занимает весь объем раздела / оставшиеся 12Гб.

Рассмотрите возможность уменьшить дамп базы данных, использовать не полный дамп для работы в виртуальной машине. Или увеличивайте объем виртуальной машины с 35Гб до больших величин. Иными способами вряд ли получится решить эту проблему.